# Short horror story about a boy who finds a mummified Native American child and takes it home

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I read a short story in the '70s about a boy who finds a mummified Native American child and takes it home. It ends with the boy looking up from his bed and seeing the mummy floating above him.